# Can we convert existing android project to ios using cordova or phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

I need help with some information which I couldn't find anywhere online. is it possible to convert my existing android app to ios using PhoneGap/Cordova? if it is yes, could u guys send me any link to do it. if its no, can I know why? please...

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not convert it. Code base and frameworks are to different. For making cross platform app you can use Flutter, Xamarin or others...

Answer (score 0):

Only if your android app is already a web application. Cordova and phonegap are a set of libraries for extending mobile web applications with native functionalities.

Comment: I have used web application and uploaded to build.phonegap.com site which converts the website to android and ios. Now I am able to convert to android(apk) file but while converting to Ios it is asking for key. what is that key? and where can i get it?

Comment: I have never used this site, maybe someone else can help you with this. The only keys that come to my mind are signing key for android and signing certificate for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

**Apache Cordova** is an open-source mobile development framework. It allows you to use standard web technologies - HTML5, CSS3, and JavaScript for cross-platform development. If your current Android application is a Native application; you cant convert application to iOS.

For more details : https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/overview/

[image]